# Theme a form element in drupal with template file?

Tags: forms, theming

I wanted to ask you if its possible to do following things:

My form  consists of three elements. 2 Dropdowns and one custom element.

The second dropdown values are getting rendered when I choose a value from the first dropdown (AJAX). The third element (custom) gets rendered when I choose a value from the second dropdown (AJAX).

Now the third element is like a detail view. It contains multiple values (from db).
So the third element shows only detail information from the second dropdown value.

What I want to do is to theme the third element. So you define a template file where you write your html code + the variables (values).

Later you can render this template in the other template where the form is being rendered.

How can I accomplish this?

Maybe a picture helps you:
[image]

Thanks for your help!